# Why is my RewriteRule not working? Regex matches

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite

URL should go

```
from: http://myurl.com/anything/?_escaped_fragment_=/article/1234
  to: http://myurl.com/rubriken/detail/articleuid/1234/
```

My RewriteRule looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^.*\?_escaped_fragment_=\/article/(.*)$ /rubriken/detail/articleuid/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

I tested the regex on http://regex101.com/ and it matches. But it does not work in my .htaccess and also not on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ . Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `?_escaped_fragment_=/article/1234` is not used in the RewriteRule

Use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_=/article/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /rubriken/detail/articleuid/%1/? [R=302,L]
```

Change `[R=302,L]` for `[R=301,L]` when test work well.

Comment: thx alot, `%{QUERY_STRING}` did the trick. also the `?` from your edit is needed else I get an ERR_TO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Comment: Yes, also works with `[R=301,L,QSD]` instead of `?` but only since Apache 2.4